# Vista equivalent of "netsh diag gui" on XP

Tags: windows-vista

How can I run the Windows XP command "netsh diag gui" in Windows Vista?

Comment: I thought that was in Chinese, or some other east Asian language :)

Answer (score 2):

Start -> Run -> type `netsh diag gui` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Note that this won't work on Vista.

Comment: wont work on vista

Comment: ah thx.  question is a little confusing.

Comment: yeah I needed to do a little deciphering at first too. I edited the question to what I think he meant. If it's not the case he can perform a rollback.

Answer (score 1):

In XP that will open the Help and Support Center to a page that helps you troubleshoot network diagnostics. In Vista, go to Start -> Help and Support, then type "Network Diagnostics" in the search. Click the 6th result. This is basically the Vista version of this XP support page.